# How turn external HD visible in Virtualbox Debian VM?

Tags: virtualbox, hard-disk, removable-storage

I want to clone my Virtualbox VM to a another/external HD in my computer.

My VM is a Debian 7, and I want to use the `dd` command on an external HD.

Is this possible?

When I use `# fdisk -l` only the VM appears and not the other HD.

Thanks!

Comment: The title of the question has nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: What kind of drive is that? eSATA or USB?

Comment: What OS is the VM running in?

Comment: @HaukeLaging I have change my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must assign USB devices to the VM. That is easily possible via the VirtualBox menu.